# "instance" in haskell

Tags: haskell

I cannot understand what is this "instance" means in Haskell (in line 19) :

```
16 > type Prog = [Function]
17 > data Function = Defun String String Exp
18 > --                deriving Show
19 > instance Show Function where
20 >   show (Defun n p e) = "\n" ++ n ++ "(" ++ p ++ ") { return " ++ show e ++ "; }\n"
21 >   showList [] = showString ""
22 >   showList (f:fs) = shows f . showl fs
23 >       where showl [] = showString ""
24 >             showl (f:fs) = shows f . showl fs
```

thx.

Comment: The answer to this question is 3/6 of the first results of the google query "haskell instance" (a gentle introduction to haskell,learn you a haskell and the haskell wikibook). Please make an effort to find the answer before you ask on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about [type classes](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html).

`Show` is a type class and you are defining a `Show` instance for `Function` datatype, so you can do something like

```
show (Defun "a" "b" someExpr)
```

and it will convert this to a string representation using the show definition for `Function`.
If you are from OO background then you can think like overloading the `show` function for `Function` data type.